# How translate from arabic to english?

Tags: java, web-services, api, translation

I want to develop an application/ web service that can translate from Arabic to English or Arabic to French  . I saw that we can find google translation API but it's paid so that's not an appropriate solution  .

**EDIT** :

If i want to integrate a module in java application and i have to translate all the words from arabic to french / english and i don't have to use an paid API ? Is it possible with sample code and some jars for example ? i don't have use algorithms of recognition of characters or something like this

Any help will be welcome thnx

Comment: It's too broad ? i have to translate words in arabic to french or english in java ? what's the broad in this ? @NSNoob

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with @NSNoob. The question is off topic. However I would like to post some names for quick reference.

**Free reliable translation API's:**

1) Google Translate: Google Translate

2) Microsoft Translate: Built for enterprise

3) Bing Translate: Translator Widget

4) Wordpress Translate: The WordPress Multilingual Plugin

**Paid localization and translation services:**

1) Localizer: Translate and Localize any Website or CMS with Localizer multilanguage plugin.

2) Smartling: Smartling Translation Management System

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for [Microsoft Translator Text API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx):

> Microsoft Translator Text API is a cloud-based automatic translation
>   (a.k.a. machine translation) service supporting multiple languages
>   that reach more than 95% of world's gross domestic product (GDP).
>   Translator can be used to build applications, websites, tools, or any
>   solution requiring multilanguage support.

It is free for over 1000 pages (2 million characters) per month.

Comment: Is that the engine they use to translate their knowledge base? In that case - good luck with arabic!!