# Solr search for arabic text written in latin characters

Tags: solr, arabic-support

I am using Apache Solr 8.6 for providing search functionality in a project, and I have use case to search for Arabic text written in Latin characters and vise verse. Data are located in one collection mixed of Arabic and English text.
for example:

If user search for Ahmed and there is احمد in the collection it should match.
If user search for احمد  and there Ahmed is in the collection it should match.

From my perspective I think I need to find (or buy) synonym list contains  English and Arabic synonyms like:
Ahmed,احمد
book,كتاب

my solution Is:

use stemmed synonyms list, use synonym filter at index time, and  use Arabic stem filter at query and index time.

Is there available synonym list like this.
And if my solution is valid or there is another options like products or Solr plugins I have to explore before I go with my Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating with solutions like Yamli (https://www.yamli.com/ar/) then build your own dictionary of synonyms will make the solution more simpler or use another translation service providers listed in the below post:
[How translate from arabic to english?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295299/how-translate-from-arabic-to-english/37295418#37295418)

there are some opensource projects like this https://github.com/MTG/ArabicTransliterator can help in transferring Arabic names from Arabic chars to Latin Chars.